# DataTable select help

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert datatable to List. Could you please help me with the query?

```
         var result = DataTable1.AsEnumerable().Select(e => {e.Field<int>("MID"), e.Field<string>("MTX")}).ToList();
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = ser.Serialize(result);
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide names for the properties inside your `Select` call. These names will not automatically and unambiguously resolve in this particular case. Try

```
var result = DataTable1.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new { Mid = row.Field<int>("Mid"), MTX = row.Field<string>("MTX") });
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(result);
```

Those names will then become part of the json result. Such as

```
[{"Mid":1,"MTX":"A"},{"Mid":2,"MTX":"B"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> sequence = dt.AsEnumerable();
```

or

```
List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var result = DataTable1.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(e => new object[] { e.Field<int>("MID"), e.Field<string>("MTX") })
    .ToList();
```